# Installing docker-ce on Fedora 28

Tags: docker, installation, fedora

According to docker website, installation for Fedora should be as follow:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/#set-up-the-repository

However these instruction does not work for Fedora, and you get a frustrating message "Nothing to be done"

So how can I install Docker-ce on Fedora 28

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the writing of this answer, the repo of Docker did not contain a stable version for Fedora 28
The work around is to call:

```
sudo dnf install https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/27/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-18.03.1.ce-1.fc27.x86_64.rpm
```

This will download the latest stable version at the writing of these lines.
Hope Docker will set a repo for Fedora 28 soon

Comment: There seems to be any issue with your command. Did you collacated two command in one?

Comment: Latest version: 
https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/28/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.fc28.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 9):

From fedora 28 only the edge, test and nightly version are available.

To install docker-ce edge you can enable the edge repo:

```
dnf config-manager --set-disabled docker-ce-stable
dnf config-manager --set-enabled docker-ce-edge
dnf install docker-ce
```

Comment: This didn't work: dnf config-manager --set-disabled docker-ce-stable

Answer (score 1):

I followed below steps on Fedora 28

Install DNF Plugins package

```
$ sudo dnf -y install dnf-plugins-core
--
Last metadata expiration check: 0:59:06 ago on Thu 05 Jul 2018 21:38:55 CDT.
Package dnf-plugins-core-2.1.5-4.fc28.noarch is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Setup stable repository

```
$ sudo dnf config-manager \
--add-repo \
https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/docker-ce.repo
--
Adding repo from: https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/docker-ce.repo
```

Enable the edge and test repositories

```
$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled docker-ce-edge
$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled docker-ce-test
```

Install Docker CE

```
$ sudo dnf install docker-ce
....
Userid     : "Docker Release (CE rpm) <docker@docker.com>"
Fingerprint: 060A 61C5 1B55 8A7F 742B 77AA C52F EB6B 621E 9F35 
From       : https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/gpg
```

Start docker

```
$  sudo systemctl start docker
```

Verify installation

```
$ sudo docker run hello-world
```

If all goes well you should get

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
9bb5a5d4561a: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:3e1764d0f546ceac4565547df2ac4907fe46f007ea229fd7ef2718514bcec35d
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

Answer (score -1):

> installation for Fedora should be as follow

Fedora 28: A basic, simple way of getting `docker-ce` ...

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
# dnf install https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/docker-ce.repo
# dnf install docker-ce
```

You get version "18.03.1.ce.**el7**.centos" , I.e. the 'Enterprise' version.

EDIT : Also see the answer from @Sagi Forbes.